# How do I change the color of a cell under a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on changing the background color of individual cells within a column using a conditional statement like the example below, but I have not been able to successfully accomplish anything. I know it's probably setup incorrectly and I've never used JavaScript before.

```
document.getElementById("Table").onload = function();

Table.rows[1].cells[4].onload = function() {    
    let tableCell = var
    if (tableCell > 92) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    } else if ( tableCell > 90) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
};
```

Any and all help is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and to programming in general. Did you follow any tutorial to write that code? How did you get there? There are some really weird lines there :)
Also, could you post your HTML code as well?

Comment: `document.getElementById("Table").onload = function();` is a syntax error. Are you checking the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after getting clarification see the first part of this answer example for insight, the second part for further learning.

First you'll just change the `onclick` to `onload` on the table element. Changed to `onclick` just for this example but `onload` will fire the method also once on your project. Go ahead and click the table in the example after hitting the "run snippet" button to see result.

First you need a reference to the table object to get the [HTMLTableCollection](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp) which you'll then first loop the rows, and then the subsequent cells of each row. You grab the number value from `innerHTML` on each pass and use `parseInt` to get a number instead of a string which you can then compare via expressions in an if statement on each iteration as shown in the example. If a number is not passed, the `try` and `catch` blocks will alert you to error in the script for correction. Hope this helps and best of luck in your endeavor!

```js
parseCells = (theTable) => {
  // First loop the table rows.
  for(let r = 0, l = theTable.rows.length; r < l; r++) {
    // Second loop the rows column cells.
    for(let c = 0, e = theTable.rows[r].cells.length; c < e; c++) {
     try {
      // Giving a random number between for innerHTML 0-100 before referencing the cell in a variable for example.
      theTable.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
      // Get the contents and convert to number from string and set the current cell.      
      let currentCellNumber = parseInt(theTable.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML),
                currentCell = theTable.rows[r].cells[c];
      // If the contents are numbers and can be parsed via expression then change colors.
        if (currentCellNumber > 92) {
          currentCell.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        } else if (currentCellNumber > 90) {
          currentCell.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
        } else {
          currentCell.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
      }
      // If there was error like cell contents aren't actually numbers, or table wasn't found etc, then alert via try/catch.
      catch {
        alert('Something is wrong with the input, are you sure your table cells only have numbers?')
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: gray 1px solid;
  transition: background-color .35s ease;
}
```

```html
<strong>Click repeatedly to watch the value/color changes</strong>
<table onclick="parseCells(this)">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For the sake of learning, hopefully this helps further. Cheers

```js
const tablex = document.getElementById('theTable'),
     clicked = document.getElementById('coordinates');

randomColor = () => {
  return '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
}

colorMe = (that) => {
  that.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
  clicked.innerHTML = that.parentNode.rowIndex + '/' + that.cellIndex;
}

colorCell = () => {
  
  try {
  const xInput = document.getElementById('theX'),
        yInput = document.getElementById('theY'),
        theCell = tablex.rows[xInput.value].cells[yInput.value];
        
    theCell.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
    clicked.innerHTML = xInput.value + '/' + yInput.value;
    
  } catch {
    alert('Check your x/y buddy, there are not that many cells... 0 - 2');
  }
  
}
```

```css
td {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border: gray 1px dotted;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<strong>Click a box, or define one specifically below : <br/>
Most recently colored cell X/Y coordinates:  <span id="coordinates" style="color:blue;font-size:130%"></span><br/>
<strong>Or a specific cell at a time;</strong><br/>
x: <input id="theX" type="number" maxlength="1">
y: <input id="theY" type="number" maxlength="1">
<button type="button" onclick="colorCell()">Color it</button>
<br/>

<table id="theTable">
  <tr>
    <td onclick="colorMe(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="colorMe(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="colorMe(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="colorMe(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="colorMe(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="colorMe(this)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="colorMe(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="colorMe(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="colorMe(this)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It’s very hard to learn from a block of code with no explanation or reference.

Comment: @DavidThomas agreed, though that's how many of us learned I wouldn't mind updating with a more concise explanation. However the space is limited to do so. Could you suggest some specific points to touch on that might better assist future readers and I'll adjust accordingly if it doesn't require too much time? The point of the example was to encourage tinkering, not necessarily provide tutorial but I do agree with your point.

Comment: So I'm still slightly confused... I'm trying to accomplish this onload and in an if else statement. Essentially if the value is greater than 92 = green; greater than 90 =orange; everything below 90 is red. How would I get that?

Comment: @surferpeeps see updated answer with the first snippet answering your question, cheers!